# Friedman's SCG function

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Today i discovered the Friedman's subcubic graph function and i have some question.

1) Why the valence of the gaphs $G_{n}$ is limited to 3? Can we make a faster growing variation of the function by using more higher value, or even an increasing value with $_{n}$?

2) Like the TREE() function, can we make a faster growing variation of SCG using labeled graph?

Answer (score 4):

(1) SCG(k) is well defined because we obtain a well-quasi-order (wqo) when we order subcubic graphs by topological minors (a.k.a. homeomorphic embedding). For subcubic graphs topological minors are equivalent to minors. The Robertson-Seymour graph minor theorem says we get a wqo where we order all graphs by minors (in general minors and topological minors or not equivalent as they are for subcubic graphs, and in general topological minors do not give a wqo). So, we can ignore the subcubic condition (or replace it with higher valence) and play the same game, but we may need to replace "topological minor" with "minor" (topological minor does give a wqo in some cases).

(2) TREE(k) looks at k-labeled trees and inf and label preserving embeddings. We cannot look at in preserving embedding when we have cycles; so, I don't see how to make a labeled version of SCG(k). Though that's not to say some other labeled version doesn't exist.